# Как получить ID только что созданной роли Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Допустим, я хочу сделать пользователям бота возможность создать их собственную роль, указав имя роли и hex-цвет. Вот как я создаю роль:

```
let rName = 'Моя суперкрутая роль';
let rColor = '#123456';

message.guild.roles.create({
    data: {
        name: rName,
        color: rColor
    },
    reason: 'Создание собственной роли'
});
```

Ну и теперь вопрос: я хочу выдать сразу же эту роль создателю, но взять и найти её по имени роли не могу, т.к. есть вероятность, что пользователи создадут 2 роли с одинаковым названием. Как узнать ID только что созданной роли?

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager метод create вернет промис с объектом включая ид, смотрите документацию, сам объект роли https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role

Comment: @Unbywyd напишите нормальный ответ с примером. и user.add role добавьте. или давайте я

Comment: user.roles.add(role), https://stackoverflow.com/a/61238160/4496422

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать `await` или `.then`, т.к. создание роли возвращает `promise` с информацией о созданной роли.

```js
let rName = 'Моя суперкрутая роль';
let rColor = '#123456';

let newRole = await message.guild.roles.create({
    data: {
        name: rName,
        color: rColor
    },
    reason: 'Создание собственной роли'
});
console.log(newRole.id)
```

```js
message.guild.roles.create({
    data: {
        name: rName,
        color: rColor
    },
    reason: 'Создание собственной роли'
}).then(newRole => {
   console.log(newRole.id)
})
```